# Create dictionary of groups from Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, python-2.7, dictionary, dataframe

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
   a  b
0  2  4
1  6  7
2  2  5
```

What I want is a dictionary (or some similar type of data structure) that keeps track of corresponding values of 'b' for values of 'a'.  The output for this dataframe would look like this:

```
'2'  :  [4, 5]
'6'  :  [7]
```

I know I could do this with a loop but I'm wondering if there are any faster and more concise built in functions I could use instead. I'm thinking there may be a way to use `groupby` but I only want the values in 'b', not the whole column.

Comment: `df.groupby('a').agg(list).b.to_dict()`

Comment: `df.groupby('a')['b'].apply(list).to_dict()` from the linked thread worked for me.